# Como modificar un archivo JSON desde html

Tags: javascript, html, json

Tengo el siguiente código, el cual convierte las entradas de un form a JSON:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Aca tenemos un formulario cualquiera. Este formulario, con id "holamundo", solo tiene un campo con nombre "hola" y valor "mundo"-->
<form action="?" id="holamundo">
    <input type="text" name="hola" value="mundo">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
    // Esta función se encargar de transformar el formulario a un archivo jsondd
    function form2json(formID) {
        // Obtenemos el objeto DOM del formulario
        var form = document.getElementById(formID);

        // Obtenemos un objeto que contiene los campos del formulario, usando la función de Jquery "serializeArray" y luego los transformo en un objeto en el que los atributos "name" de cada campo del formulario pasan a ser las claves del objeto; y los "value" los valores.
        var serializedForm = $(form).serializeArray().reduce(function(result, field){
            if (result.hasOwnProperty(field.name)) {
                if (Array.isArray(result[field.name])) {
                    result[field.name].push(field.value);
                } else {
                    result[field.name] = [result[field.name], field.value];
                }
            } else {
                result[field.name] = field.value;
            }
            return result;
        }, {});

        // Transformo los campos a una cadena JSON
        var jsonForm = JSON.stringify(serializedForm);

        // Agrego el tipo MIME del archivo y la codificación de caracteres
        var jsonFileData = 'data:application/json;charset=UTF-8,';

        // Codifico la cadena JSON con la función "encodeURIComponent" para que pueda ser parte del atributo "href" y luego lo agrego.
        jsonFileData += encodeURIComponent(jsonForm);

        // Devuelvo el resultado
        return jsonFileData;
    }
</script>
<!-- Este link por si solo no hace nada. Pero con el evento "click", cambia el atributo "href" por el contenido del archivo, que se obtiene al llamar a la funcion "form2json". El atributo "href" no solo puede contener links; tambien puede contener archivos, indicando tipo de archivo y codificación de caracteres (si es archivo de texto). El atributo "download" indica el nombre del archivo. -->
<a href="#" onclick="this.href=form2json('holamundo')" download="holamundo.json">Descargar formulario</a>
```

En la última linea el link descarga un archivo JSON de nombre holamundo.json. Lo que quiero hacer es que en lugar de descargar el JSON, se modifique un archivo  json del mismo nombre que está en la misma carpeta que mi index.html(que es el archivo donde está este código). Se que debería llamar a la función form2json, pero no se como ni de donde(soy nuevo en html). ¿Cómo puedo modificar el archivo?. Gracias

Comment: JSON es un objeto de javascrip su nombre lo dice, no lo puedes modificar desde HTML, pero si desde  javascript, y si es posible modificarlo desde el lado del cliente, en w3c explican como acceder a un objeto y modificar sus valorers https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp

Answer (score 0):

No se si eso se puede hacer desde el lado del cliente.
Tendrás que utilizar lógica del lado del servidor.
Espero equivocarme, estaré atento a otras respuestas.